# Func<T> in Lambda expression with LinQ to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a problem with this snippet of code. i Use LinQ to entity

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
using (var db = new DiagEntities())
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DiagTab).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {

        string name = property.Name;
        if (name == "ID_Diag") { continue; } // no column 1 and 2 
        if (name == "Reponse") { continue; } 

        Func<DiagTab, byte> accessor = (Func<DiagTab, byte>)property
                                            .GetMethod
                                            .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<DiagTab, byte>));

        int sum = db.DiagTabs.Sum(p => accessor(p));  // invoke error

        dictionary.Add(name, sum);                      
    }
    bouba.DataSource = dictionary;
    bouba.DataBind();
```

A compilation I have this error that appears on this line and I do not understand why:

```
int sum = db.DiagTabs.Sum(p => accessor(p))
```

> The node type 'Invoke' LINQ expression is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Can you help me for this problem? I should use LINQkit or other?

Comment: Are you sure that is a compilation error?

Comment: sorry, I'm on VS 2015.
when I run my web page to test the software hangs and appointed me this error and highlights the line of code.
I can not see my web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 major problems with your code.

First, neither `Enumerable` nor `Queryable` has a `Sum` method for `byte`, so the closest would be the one that works with `int`.

Second and more important, LINQ to Entities works primarily with `Queryable`, which in turn uses `Expression<Func<...>>` (in contrast with `Enumerable` that uses just `Func<...>`). Your code is trying to combine them by creating an expression from func, but as the error message states, that is not supported.

The solution is to build expression using the classes/methods from the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace - [Expression.Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355908(v=vs.110).aspx) for creating parameter(s), [Expression.Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662(v=vs.110).aspx) for property accessor(s), [Expression.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) for changing the type and [Expression.Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343032(v=vs.110).aspx) to put them all together, like this

```
foreach (var property in typeof(DiagTab).GetProperties())
{    
    string name = property.Name;
    if (name == "ID_Diag") { continue; } // no column 1 and 2 
    if (name == "Reponse") { continue; } 

    // selector = (DiagTab source) => (int)source.Property
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DiagTab), "source");
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<DiagTab, int>>(
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(source, property), typeof(int)),
        source);

   int sum = db.DiagTabs.Sum(selector);
   dictionary.Add(name, sum);                      
}
```

Comment: Thx Thx Thx Ivan. It's perfect !